# MySQL: Not possible to login to DB without sudo (mysql-server-5.7)

Tags: mysql, linux, permissions

I have installed mysql-server through `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`.

No when I want to login with `mysql -u root -p` I get the message `ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`.

But when I login with `sudo mysql -u root -p` it is possible, everything works fine.

What do I need to fix, that I can login to mysql without sudo command?

Comment: Login as a root account user then you can run any command without `sudo`

Answer (score 2):

That's a permission issue, and working as intended : by default only the root linux user can execute the mysql daemon.

To allow it for other users, throw that command :

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/
```

After that you have to restart the mysql daemon. Depending on your linux kernel, try one of these:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

or

```
service mysqld restart
```

Note that all this is NOT necessary and will lower the security. I see no reason why one would have to execute mysql with a normal user, except maybe on a shared server where several instances of mysql are running under the control of each user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually the problem was a slightly different one, I posted an answer that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/763336/cannot-enter-phpmyadmin-as-root-mysql-5-7/763359#763359

MySQL 5.7 changed the secure model, root login requires sudo now.

The solution is to create a new user and give them privileges.

The linked answer above solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with mysql 5.7

Because normal user not having a priviledges to get the access
..

Open mysql :

sudo mysql -u root -P

Create new user and add all privileges to that user :

replace username and password according to your need. Replace avi and avi123

```
CREATE USER 'avi'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'avi123';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'avi'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Only root user needs sudo for login . You can create a new user with all privileges and can be logged in without using sudo.

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost'; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Login:

```
mysql -u newuser -p
```